# Coding <ul> <li> menu to fit within main <div>

Tags: html, css, list, menu

**EDIT:** I have found this code, which appears to be sorta working the way I want it to. You can check it out live at EDIT - I still can't get it to sit within my #main div though! I've tried using both 100% and 990px within  #menu span for width - neither seem to work.

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <span></span>
</div>

#menu {
  text-align: justify;
}

#menu * {
  display: inline;
}

#menu span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

**END EDIT**

I have a menu I'm having some issues with - mainly horizontal issues :)

Basically, when you view the website in Chrome, the menu is centered the way I want it to be.

When you view the website in FireFox, the menu is 5-10px short on the right side.

And when you view it in Internet Explorer, the menu is not sitting left and is overflowing off of the right side of the page.

View it for yourself at: EDIT (Keep in mind, index2.php here, not the original index)

So my question is:

How can I style/code this menu correctly to fit within my parent div?

I did look through previous topics with similar questions, however, was unable to make anything work. Thank you in advance :)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EDIT </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<style>

#sliderwrapper {width:635px;}

#control  {
  text-align:right;
  margin-top:5px;
}

#control a  {
  background:#87e7fa;
  padding:0 5px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:5px;
}

#control a.active {background:#265db9;}
#control a span {visibility:hidden;}

.sexyslider-control span {display:none;}

.sexyslider-title {
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}



</style>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sexyslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#slider").SexySlider({
        width      : 981,
        height     : 500,
        delay      : 3000,
        strips     : 18,
        autopause  : false,
        <!--navigation : '#navigation',--!>
        control    : '#control',
    direction    : 'left',
        effect     : 'fade'
      });
    });
</script>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"><img src="images/header.gif" alt="" /></div>


<div id="main">

    <ul>
    <h2><li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.php">Meet Our Team</a>
    <li><a href="office.php">Office Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="first.php">First Visit</a></li>
    <li><a href="dental.php">Dental Topics</a></li>
    <li><a href="tour.php">Office Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li></h2>
    </ul>
    <div id="sliderwrapper" class="clearfloat">
        <div id="slider" style="width:100%">
                    <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" "/>
                                    <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt=""  "/>
                    <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" " />
                                    <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt=""  "/>
                    <img src="images/slide4.jpg" alt=""  "/>
                                    <img src="images/slide5.jpg" alt=""  "/>
                    <img src="images/slide6.jpg" alt=""  "/>
                </div>

<div id="control" style="margin-top:10px; margin-right:-347px;"></div>
</div>  
</div>      



    <div id="footer"><img src="images/footer.gif" alt=""/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color: #87e7fa;
font-size:100%;
text-align:center;
}
#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background:url('images/bg.gif') repeat-y;
width:1200px;
}
#header {
    width:1200px;
height:358px;
}
#main {
    width:990px;
height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;

    }

#footer {
clear:both;
width:1200px;
height:354px;
}

h2 {
    font-family:soos_font;
    text-decoration:none;   
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); 
    }

ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:10 0;
padding:0;

}



li
{
display:inline;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}


a:link,a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#87e7fa;
text-align:center;
padding:7px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
border-radius:5px;
margin:0 auto;

}

a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#3650a2;
}
```

Comment: In firefox and chrome (OSX) I'm seeing the menu overflow the right side. Also, you should put your scripts right before `</body>`

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Also, I want the scripts WITHIN the body? I always thought before.
Correct me if I'm wrong please!

Comment: You've got a few issues here: you shouldn't be using `h2` for your navigation, use `nav` instead (if you're targeting HTML5). `h2` should never appear directly inside `ul`. and using `#menu *` inside your CSS is an incredibly bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update you css

**css**

```
#main {
    width:990px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#main ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main li{
    display:inline-block;
    /*width:100%;*/
    margin:0 3px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="main">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="team.php">Meet Our Team</a>
    <li><a href="office.php">Office Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="first.php">First Visit</a></li>
    <li><a href="dental.php">Dental Topics</a></li>
    <li><a href="tour.php">Office Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear:both;"/>
</div>
```

here is the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/SBMpS/1/)

Also don't wrap `li` in to `h2`, this is not a valid code.

Comment: This works excellent in everything except for Internet Explorer :) Any suggestions for that?

Comment: which version of IE you are talking about?

Comment: I believe my version is IE9.

Comment: for IE 7 we have to use display:inline; in the place of display:inline-block;

Comment: This is how it appears to me:
http://digitaldistrict.ca/ie9.jpg

It is stacking rather than placing horizontally.

Comment: use display:inline; in the place of display:inline-block; I think this will solve your issue